# Is there a way to change the default Material color definitions?

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design

The definition of `Colors.black` is `0xFF000000`. Is there a way to directly edit if not override this definition mapping with a different color code ?

For example if I were to then type `Colors.black` , it would give me something like `0xFF78909C`.

Based off the [Color class documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Colors-class.html).

Comment: Why shouldn't black be black?

Comment: Wanted to use a different shade of black , in my case specifically #2f2f2f mentioned in [this thread](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25356/why-not-use-pure-black-000-and-pure-white-fff). They cover why we shouldn't use absolute black and white in design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you could `hide` the `Colors` class from the `material` package:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' hide Colors;
```

And then create your `Colors` `Class` as follows:

```
class Colors {
  Colors._();
  static const Color black = Color(0x0xFF78909C);
}
```

---

A better approach might be, depending on your scenario, to create a custom `Colors` `Class` like the following:

```
class ThemeColors {
  ThemeColors._();
  static const Color black = Color(0xFF78909C);
}
```

Which we can use like the following:

```
ThemeColors.black;
```

Without the need to `hide Colors;` from the `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';`